# How to scale DIV elements with CSS3 and keep the distances between them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to scale some divs inside a 'workspace' div. The problem I have are with the distance between them (I lose it).

I have read a lot of post about CSS3 transform, in special about scale and translate and origin, but I can't solve the problem...

Can someone explain me how can I keep them? I show one code using a mousewheel plugin, regards.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="workspace">
        <div style="z-index: 101;"><img src="image1-300x300.jpg" /></div>
        <div style="z-index: 102; left: 300px; top: 400px;"><img src="image2-400x400.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
 #workspace {
            width: 1600px;
            height: 900px;
            position: absolute;
            margin: auto;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            display: inline;
        }
            #workspace > div {
                display: inline;
                position: absolute;
            }
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var scale = 1;  // scale of the image
            var xLast = 0;  // last x location on the screen
            var yLast = 0;  // last y location on the screen
            var xImage = 0; // last x location on the image
            var yImage = 0; // last y location on the image

            // if mousewheel is moved
            $("#workspace").mousewheel(function (e, delta) {
                // find current location on screen 
                var xScreen = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
                var yScreen = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;

                // find current location on the image at the current scale
                xImage = xImage + ((xScreen - xLast) / scale);
                yImage = yImage + ((yScreen - yLast) / scale);

                // determine the new scale
                if (delta > 0) {
                    scale *= 2;
                }
                else {
                    scale /= 2;
                }
                scale = scale < 1 ? 1 : (scale > 64 ? 64 : scale);

                // determine the location on the screen at the new scale
                var xNew = (xScreen - xImage) / scale;
                var yNew = (yScreen - yImage) / scale;

                // save the current screen location
                xLast = xScreen;
                yLast = yScreen;

                // redraw

                $('#mosaicContainer > div').each(function() {
                    $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(' + scale + ')' + 'translate(' + xNew + 'px, ' + yNew + 'px' + ')')
                    .css('-webkit-transform-origin', (xImage) + 'px ' + (yImage) + 'px');
                });

                return false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: So you're trying to make the divs larger, and yet keep the space between them the same? Do you plan on letting the divs move close towards the sides of the screen?

Comment: Yes to the first question, and to the second If the divs go outside of the screen it's not a problem.

Comment: Here's a JS Fiddle so that people can look into your code: http://jsfiddle.net/4LHNN/